# How do I use NPM in my vanillaJS, html, css project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, webpack

I have a project that has 3 html files namely index.html, about.html and resource.html.

It has two css files, style.css and style1.css. It has two javascript files, script.js and script1.js. Index.html uses style.css and script.js. about.html uses style1.css and script1.js. resource.js also uses style1.css and script1.js. I wanted tried initializing a NPM project, but it asks for an entry point. What do I do?

I want to use webpack to bundle my project, and for that I need to use NPM. This project is fully vanilla.

Comment: check this link https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

Answer (score 5):

As it mentioned in the comments, you should download [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) first. 
Node js come with its package manager called `npm`.

In my opinion for your project, the `webpack` bundler could be confusing at first, so I think you should use `Parcel` instead.

Steps for your project:

**step1**

After you installed `node` with `npm` in your project directory folder run the following script in a terminal: 
`npm init -y` 
It will create a `package.json` file int the root directory of your project.

**step2**

run the following script in the terminal which will install parcel bundler 
`npm install --save-dev parcel`

**step3**
in the `package.json` file you will find a line with`"scripts"`.
add the following lines to it:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "parcel ./*.html",
    "build": "parcel build ./*.html"
  },
```

After you done it, you should just run the following script in your terminal, which will start a dev server on your local machine with automate reload on **localhost:1234**

`npm run start`

If you want to bundle your html project, then just run the following script: 
`npm run build`

For better understanding how **Parcel** works, [here](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/) is the tools documentation.

Hope it will helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be specifically related to the `entrypoint` question asked when you run `npm init`. The value you specify there will be set to th property `main`, in `package.json`.

That property specifies what file/module will be loaded when someone `import`s or `require`s you package. As it doesn't look like you are creating an npm package that will be imported and simply wants to use `npm` to install dependencies, you don't need to care about it. You can use the default value provided: `index.js`, even if it doesn't exist.

You can read about it here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#main