# Using qs library from plain javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, module

Is it possible to use the https://github.com/ljharb/qs querystring parsing and stringifying library in plain javascript in a browser?

If so, how would I go about doing that?

If not, are there any alternatives I can use to get similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a simple node js project, add dependancy to qs, use the library in your html, package and then your html, gs js and other files that qs depends on will be placed in your dist folder. Look at node js simple project [How do I use NPM in my vanillaJS, html, css project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470483/how-do-i-use-npm-in-my-vanillajs-html-css-project) and https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack